# QuerySet Django, need to get multiple result on one

Tags: django, django-queryset

I got this model :

```
class BfMatchingNafRome(models.Model):
    code_naf = models.CharField(null=False,max_length=255)
    libelle_naf = models.CharField(null=True,max_length=255)
    code_rome = models.CharField(null=True,max_length=255)
```

I want to put some data in a table.

```
  {% for match in matching %}
   <tr>
       <th scope="row">{{match.code_naf}}</th>
       <td>{{match.libelle_naf}}</td>

       <td>
           {% for i in match.code_rome %}
           {{i}}
           {% endfor %}
       </td>
  {% endfor %}
```

I use :

```
matching = BfMatchingNafRome.objects.filter(code_naf__lte=activity.code_activity).order_by('code_naf')
```

I've tried absolutely all I can find on stack overflow, google, youtube, but I cant link my datas.
I just get, on my view, one line with code_naf - code_rome.
I want one line per code_naf with all code_rome for this code_naf.

I create multiple entries (for an other view I need one data by entry).

But, for this view, I need to receive datas linked.

Thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

code_naf is a `CharField` so they are compared not by value but *lexicographically*. For exapmle '9' > '89', since the first characters are '8' and '9', and '8' is first in the alphabet. Be sure that you compare it properly

Comment: I want to compare them between them. If a code_naf is similar to another, I need to get the two entries in one